# How to load a csv file to R studio?

Tags: r, csv

```
data <- read.csv(C:\\Users\\Werner Bouwer\\Documents\\projects\\SQL-Cloud-Experience\\Fitabase Data 4.12.16-5.12.16\\heartrate_seconds_merged.csv")
Error: unexpected '\\' in "data <- read.csv(C:\\"
```

Comment: It looks like you are missing the leading `"` before the C:

Comment: Tried running it with the " but still getting an error saying the file does not exist.

Comment: You should set the working directory to the folder where the file is, and then use read.csv("heartrate_seconds_merged.csv")

Comment: Also you can try `fname <- file.choose()` to interactively search for the file through your directory structure. Assuming you find it, you can then use `read.csv(fname)`. Also you can use the Files tab in the lower right window of RStudio to search for the file.